# How to share cursor between fragments/activities

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-contentprovider, android-cursorloader

I'm trying to build an application that will have list/detail panes built with fragments. <strike>List is created from the `ContentProvider`. When clicked on the list the details is populated or activity created. In action similar to gmail application. How the data should be shared/passed between fragments/activities?</strike>

Population of the list wasn't that hard, but how can I pass the selection to the details fragment (either in the same activity or another activity)? Should I query again and returned result used in details?

It needs to be like gmail app, so swipe left/right should then change the details accordingly to the same order as the list is either in the single pane layout or dual pane layout.

I think for this I need to share the `Cursor` returned by the `CursorLoader` to keep the same order. Then swipes would increase/decrease the index and would display correct item.

Also as I already loaded data, I wanted to reuse it without new queries.

Could someone point me to the right direction, what you would you do to achieve that (no code but algorithm/steps)?

At the moment I have 2 activities *list* and *detail*, the *list* has dual and single panel layout and *list fragment* with *details fragment* are used, *detail* has just single pane with *details fragment*. I think I could reduce it to be a single activity and juggle the fragments but don't know if it will be good.

Comment: pass an id or full Uri in the Intent's extras

Comment: when creating an Intent to the details activity,  pass an Uri that was used to get the original Cursor and then use it to recreate the Cursor in the details activity,  no Cursor is Parcelable so you cannot pass it via extras

Comment: if you **REALLY** need to pass the Cursor via extras create a custom AbstractWindowedCursor and use CursorWindow which is Parcelable to pass the data

Comment: I **REALLY** :) would like to know how it should be done correctly, based on gmail app description. If Sharing cursor is wrong, than lets not find a way to do it:) All I need is to know how to keep track of the list results and details, like it is on the gmail app.

Comment: So just pass the Uri, google folks didnt create a Parcelable Cursor so i think they did it on purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did then was:

activity holding the fragment(s) will do:

1. implement `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>`
2. call the `getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(ALL_DATA_LOADER_ID, null, this);`
3. pass arguments of the `LoaderCallbacks` to the fragments that also implements `LoaderCallbacks`
4. call the `getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(ALL_DATA_LOADER_ID, null,
                   this);` whenever data was changed outside of the `ContentProvider` means

This way I'm sharing the same cursor between fragments. Between activities I'm exchanging (via Intent) the data needed to request the same dataset and selection id if needed.

Comment: Is there not a risk of race-conditions/concurrency bug. If two different fragments / views are sharing 1 cursor, and calling methods such as cursor.moveToFirst() would they not have the potential to upset each other?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to pass data from one activity to another :

```
        intent = new Intent(this, ProductListActivity.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable(PRODUCT_LIST, productList);
        bundle.putString(KEY_WORD, keyWord);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(intent);
```

If you're in an activity and want to pass data to a fragment in that activity, just use setters from that fragment

EDIT : Since last comment, implement a class to handle your object with the Serializable interface :

```
public class MyDBObject implements Serializable {
//Stuff
}
```

Then when you fetch from your DB, return or a `MyDBObject`, or a `List<MyDBObject>`

Finally, when you need to pass the data, just use

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SourceActivity.this, TargetActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("DB_OBJECTS", ArrayList<MyDBObject>mDBObject); // For a list
intent.putExtra("DB_OBJECT", mDBOject); //For a single object
```

Comment: yes, that's how I can do it and am doing it, but how to pass the cursor (the results list) to use in details view for back/forth navigation? or should I just in details view run query again?